# Nodes and links in D3 (React): How to connect nodes through my links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

We're trying to connect our nodes but it doesn't work. The nodes are beeing displayed but not their connections(links).

This is our code:

```
 CreateNodesAndLinks() {
    let canvas = d3.select(this.refs.anchor)
    let width = 800
    let height = 600


    let companyNodes = Object.values(this.state.data.CompanyNodes)
    let links = Object.values(this.state.data.Links)

    companyNodes = this.filter_array_values(companyNodes)
    links = this.filter_array_values(links)

    console.log(companyNodes)
    console.log(links)

    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(companyNodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    const svg = canvas.append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

    const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#999")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .join("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", item => Math.sqrt(item.percent_share));

    const companyNode = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(companyNodes)
      .join("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .call(this.drag(simulation));

    companyNode.append("title")
      .text(item => item.company_id);

    simulation.on("tick", () => {
      link
        .attr("x1", d => d.from_id.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.from_id.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.to_id.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.to_id.y);

      companyNode
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });

    return svg.node();
  }
```

render function:

```
  render() {

    return (
        <div>

          <g ref="anchor" />

        </div>
    );
  }
```

And this is how our companyNodes and links Object looks like: https://ibb.co/b5bsRLg

So the connection is between "from_id" and "to_id"

And we don't know what we're doing wrong. Maybe someone can help

Probably there's something wrong with the

```
simulation.on("tick", () => {
          link...
```

method but we can't figure it out.

Comment: why are you setting stroke on a `g` element?

Comment: we're very new to this so  we just tried out some code from the internet and it worked. But it didn't work if we want to display the links. But we found our mistake. I'll leave the solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

We found our mistakes and maybe it could help someone.

This...

```
 const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(companyNodes)
          .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
```

...had to be changed to this:

```
 const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(companyNodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.company_id))  //company_id is the identifier for one specific company we have in companyNodes
```

And the other thing was that we had to rename every `from_id` to `source` and `to_id` to `target` because it seems like `d3` is only working with `source` and `target`